# Finding occurrences of 'Y' or 'N' in a string

Tags: python, string, printing, comparison

How can I make it so both strings compare correctly? So there is an output if the string `Answers` contained an `'N'` in it?

```
def stringSearcher():             #Seperates and returns 2 strings from .txt file
    f = open("QuestionTree.txt", "r")
    currentLine = f.readline()
    for line in f:
        if Answer in line: 
            yesnos, answerOrQuestion = line.split(',')
            return answerOrQuestion, yesnos

while True:

    Answer = raw_input("Y or N: ")              #User input
    answerOrQuestion, yesnos = stringSearcher() #allows usage of Return variables

    if yesnos == Answer:     #Will compare the 'Y' in string but not 
        print answerOrQuestion
```

---

This is what the output looks like:

---

```
Y or N: N    #Not print the N in the text file
Y or N: Y 
In the Towers?

Y or N: YN
Y or N: YY
Old Tower?

Y or N: YYY
7 floors tall?

Y or N: ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestCode.py", line 11, in <module>
    Answer = raw_input("Y or N: ")
```

---

This is what text file looks like:

---

,Is it a dorm?
Y,In the Towers?
YY,Old Tower?
YYY,7 floors tall?
YYYY,Is it Carey?
YYYYY,Carey Hall
YYYYN,Troutman Hall
YYYN,Is it Wheeler?
N,West of Mission?
NY,S of Broomfield?
NYY,CMU Owned?
NYYY,Kewadin
NYYN,B-Ball Court?
NYYNY,Is it Lexington?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I run my execute my program, it will only give output for "Y".

Comment: Yes, but what is your question?

Comment: Do you want to know why? Do you want to know how to change this behavior? Ask us a question.

Comment: How can I make it so both strings compare correctly? So there is an output if the string "Answers" contained an 'N' in it?

Comment: Ah. You should add that to your question, so people will know how to answer you.

Comment: It's best for the title of your question to be fairly short, and to elaborate in the body of the question. (We're very picky about these sorts of things).

Answer (score 1):

change

```
def stringSearcher():
```

to

```
def stringSearcher(Answer):
```

Comment: It didn't work... TypeError: string Searcher() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: also changing stringSearcher() to stringSearcher(Answer) in the while loop.

Comment: The changes didn't change the output for the string including 'N', how would i fix that?

Comment: could you show me the sample string line in .txt file which contains a "N" ?

Comment: I can't fix the format of it, everytime i try i get an "You have a lot of code, why not add some details"

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def stringSearcher(Answer):
    f = open("QuestionTree.txt", "r")
    currentLine = f.readline()
    for line in f:
        if re.match(Answer, line): 
            yesnos, answerOrQuestion = line.split(',')
            return answerOrQuestion, yesnos

while True:

    Answer = raw_input("Y or N: ")
    answerOrQuestion, yesnos = stringSearcher(Answer)

    if Answer == yesnos:     #Will compare the 'Y' in string but not 
        print answerOrQuestion
```